# PDFBOX extract image with Color space Indexed

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm trying to extract all the images from pdf by using the below code, it work fine for all images except the images with color space indexed.

```
try (final PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("./pdfs/22.pdf"))){

    PDPageTree list = document.getPages();
    for (PDPage page : list) {
        PDResources pdResources = page.getResources();
        int i = 1;
        for (COSName name : pdResources.getXObjectNames()) {
            PDXObject o = pdResources.getXObject(name);
            if (o instanceof PDImageXObject) {
                PDImageXObject image = (PDImageXObject)o;
                String filename = OUTPUT_DIR + "extracted-image-" + i + ".png";
                ImageIO.write(image.getImage(), "png", new File(filename));
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

} catch (IOException e){
    System.err.println("Exception while trying to create pdf document - " + e);
}
```

Do i miss something? How can I extract such type of images??

Comment: What pdfbox version are you using? What doesn't work?

Comment: Dear @TilmanHausherr
I'm using 2.0.16.
when getting the image and save it , it will appear as small box 1X1 pixel.

Comment: The current version is 2.0.18. Can you share the PDF? Also try the ExtractImages command line tool.